# It is possible to disable all the fields in the table and put condition to enable certain fields that needed??

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to disable the table once I select the marital status and I only want to enable the name field and marital status selection based on certain condition. But it seem like not working. Perhaps have other way to code it ?

### Example code

```
<form name="mainform" method="post" action="abc.jsp" >
<table id="style1">
    <tr>
        <td>name
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>age
            <input type="text" name="age" id="age">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>tel no.
            <input type="text" name="telno" id="telno">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>email
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>marital status
            <select name="ms" id="ms" onChange="fnTest();">
                <option>married</option>
                <option>single</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
function fnTest() {

document.mainform.getElementById("style1").disabled = true;

//CONDITION

document.mainform.getElementById("name").disabled = false;    }
```

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599059/jquery-animation-for-enabled-disabled-textboxes?rq=1

Comment: Sorry im not using jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y26oe3dm/) with your code and then tweaked it a bit. Is this the effect you were aiming for?

HTML:

```
<table id="style1">
    <tr>
        <td>name
            <input class='style2' type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>age
            <input class='style2' type="text" name="age" id="age"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>tel no.
            <input class='style2' type="text" name="telno" id="telno"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>email
            <input class='style2' type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>marital status
            <select class='style2' name="ms" id="ms">
                <option>Select One</option>
                <option>married</option>
                <option>single</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var fnTest = function() {
    alert('change');
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName("style2");
    for (var l=0;l<list.length;l++) {
        list[l].disabled = true;
    }
    if (true) { //Your Condition
        document.getElementById("name").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("ms").disabled = false; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById("name").disabled = true;
        document.mainform.getElementById("ms").disabled = true; 
    }
};

document.getElementById('ms').addEventListener('change', function() { fnTest(); });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding class in your inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" class='information' name="name" id="name">
```

Then try this code:

```
function toggle(bool){

    if(bool == 'true') {
       document.getElementsByClassName('information').disabled = true;
    } else {
       document.getElementsByClassName('information').disabled = false;
    }
}
```

How to call the function:

```
toggle('true');
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use `document.mainForm.getElementById` try `document.getElementById` instead.
2. Wrap you inputs in `<fieldset>` and disable it instead of `<table>`
3. You can't disable a group of controls in html and enable just one input inside this group (at least without writing extra code). To achieve the behavior just wrap the group of inputs you want to disable in `<fieldset>` and put the control which has separate rules for disabling outside this group.

Here is the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PvCYx2EPQpMrRVmPZNYO):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="mainform" method="post" action="abc.jsp">
  <table>
        <tr>
          <td>name
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <fieldset id="myform">
      <table id="style1">
        <tr>
          <td>age
            <input type="text" name="age" id="age">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>tel no.
            <input type="text" name="telno" id="telno">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>email
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>marital status
            <select name="ms" id="ms" onChange="fnTest();">
              <option>married</option>
              <option>single</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <script>
    function fnTest() {

      document.getElementById("myform").disabled = true;

      //Reverse your condition to disable name input as well

      //document.getElementById("name").disabled = true;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I guess fieldset is not very efficient to  use. Because in real case, the system page have about 50 fields..  and selection box are use to trigger which fields need to be disabled

Comment: In this case I would suggest you to look at any MVVM framework with 2 way binding. Otherwise maintaining the form with 50 fields on pure DOM API won't be fun at all. Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/NTKVTP) with knockout.js. Good luck